# How to keep SQL server connection alive and avoid timeout errors?

Tags: sql-server, connection, ado.net, database-connection, connectivity

I am working on a piece of code that looks as follows:

```
var liveConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfig.dbMainConnectionString);
liveConnection.Open();

try
{
    var itemGroup = getItems(); // this method reads any new .CSV files uploaded into an ftp server and returns a list of itemgroups

    foreach(var item in itemGroup)
    {
        // execute a stored procedure with the parameters in item using liveConnection
    } 

    liveConnection.Close();
}
catch(...) { ... }
finally(...) { ... }
```

This used to work fine for smaller files. However, we have recently started processing some large .csv files containing ~200K records and have been seeing the following kinds of errors in the logs.

- `A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`
- `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`
- `Database error: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)`

Due to the nature of the occurrence of the errors (when we are processing large files), it seems like the database server is closing the connection to my application while the file is still being processed inside the loop, leading to the error.

If this is in fact the case, my question is, **is there a setting I can use to extend this timeout to some large value so that the database server does not close the connection ?**

I know about `ConnectionTimeout` and `CommandTimeout` but both of these do not seem proper for my case since ConnectionTimout is only used while opening the connection and `CommandTimeout` is only used for the execution of each command. The default value of 30 seconds for `CommandTimeout` seems adequate for me since even though the file itself is large, each command in the loop is a simple update/insert statement.

We are not using connection pooling since this application is supposed to run only about 3 times a day to process the files and does not need to be connected to the database except these times.

I have seen similar question is SO with these errors and they all seem to point to the fact that the sql server is closing the connection, but the solutions are mostly anecdotal. I am asking if there is a specific setting I can use to make this connection long term.

Comment: Why not create connection after you read in the files?

Comment: And why not use BulkCopy or some other way to load the data into the database quicker, instead of what looks like reading the file line by line and calling a stored procedure for each line?

Comment: Sounds like you are having network issues. There is nothing that would cause the connection to get closed while it's being used. Do note that you need a `using` on the connection.

Comment: - Why not create connection after you read in the files?
Earlier this method was verifying the contents of the file by cross referencing it with the data in the database. This step has been moved into the SP, but I guess the last dev forgot to move the `liveConnection.Open()` line. This is a good catch.

Comment: - why not use BulkCopy or some other way to load the data into the database quicker?
Even though the eventual statement is an insert/ update, the SP has some code that does some error checking and reference mapping before the data is eventually inserted/ updated. We want to keep the implementation as close to stock as possible because this is part of a legacy system that we do not want to introduce widespread changes to if possible.

Comment: You should also be wrapping your connection in a `USING` statement. As coded, if your code fails inside the try the connection will never close, unless maybe you close it again inside your catch.

Comment: Could be a network issue. I am not ruling it out, @Charlieface. But wanted to know if there was any other setting that could be at play here. Because like I said, this is happening only when processing these large files. Obviously it can also be, that this has been happening for smaller files as well, but when processing large files, the network drops are more apparent.

Comment: It is being closed inside the finally block @SeanLange. Unfortunately, I do not have much idea about the design choices here because it was part of a legacy system that has not been updated since 2016.

Comment: `liveConnection.Close();` is right there at the end of the try block. I understand what you mean about legacy code though. But since you are in there this might be a good time to fix at least one part of it.

Comment: If you're running some remote queries, inside the file process you might wanna check out the remote query timeout settings, otherwise check query wait setting, maybe it needs to be increased. We process large files and sometimes also get semaphore timeouts etc. This is probably due to unstable network, so yeah, the best way to fix it is to speed up your queries so network doesn't have a chance to kill you :)